# Can I change the style of links in the Output Panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I build in VS Code, the build log goes to the Output window, and the Output window helpfully links text like "filepath:line:column" back to my source code. Cool, great feature.

But I find all the underlines quite distracting. My preference would be for clickable text to only show a different style on mouse-over. Maybe blue text with an underline ... but *only* on mouse over. I've tried to find such an option, to no avail.

In my opinion, that would be a useful option.

What I'm really doing is writing an extension that applies syntax highlighting to the Output Panel, and I would like to style the links there as well.

[image: Build output log cluttered with underlined links]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I'm aware of are the following related settings- none of which are what you're looking for:

```json
// (showing default values)
"editor.links": true,
"terminal.integrated.enableFileLinks": "on",
"terminal.integrated.showLinkHover": true,
```

There was a feature-request issue ticket raised in VS Code's GitHub repo which probably at least partially covered what you're looking for: [Disable underlining for clickable URLs #140657](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140657), but it was closed for not receiving enough community support fast enough.

I'd suggest [raising a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md) of your own clearly describing what you're looking for. You can share links to your feature request to various other dev communities to solicit support form them (following their community rules for promotion). Ex. [r/vscode](https://reddit.com/r/vscode) and [the VS Code Dev Community Slack](https://aka.ms/vscode-dev-community).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.